# Как получить идентификатор города в Новая Почта API?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telebot, новая-почта

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы создать экспресс-накладную на отделение через telegram-бот. На сайте для разработчиков `API` я нашел пример, как составить `JSON` и там есть такие параметры:

- `Sender`;
- `SenderAddress`;
- `...`

В качестве примера туда были переданы примерно такие идентификаторы отправителя/адреса...:
`5ace4a2e-13ee-11e5-add9-005056887b8d`.

Вопрос - где и как я смогу получить эти идентификаторы?

Ссылка на портал для разработчиков API:
https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556eef34a0fe4f02049c664e/operations/56261f14a0fe4f1e503fe187

Пример `JSON`, который есть на сайте:

```
{  
"apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]",
   "modelName":"InternetDocument",
   "calledMethod":"save",
   "methodProperties":{  
      "NewAddress":"1",
      "PayerType":"Sender",
      "PaymentMethod":"Cash",
      "CargoType":"Cargo",
      "VolumeGeneral":"0.1",
      "Weight":"10",
      "ServiceType":"WarehouseWarehouse",
      "SeatsAmount":"1",
      "Description":"абажур",
      "Cost":"500",
      "CitySender":"8d5a980d-391c-11dd-90d9-001a92567626",
      "Sender":"5ace4a2e-13ee-11e5-add9-005056887b8d",
      "SenderAddress":"d492290b-55f2-11e5-ad08-005056801333",
      "ContactSender":"613b77c4-1411-11e5-ad08-005056801333",
      "SendersPhone":"380991234567",
      "RecipientCityName":"Киев",
      "RecipientArea":"",
      "RecipientAreaRegions":"",
      "RecipientAddressName":"1",
      "RecipientHouse":"",
      "RecipientFlat":"",
      "RecipientName":"Тест Тест Тест",
      "RecipientType":"PrivatePerson",
      "RecipientsPhone":"380991234567",
      "DateTime":"23.09.2016"
   }
}
```

Поиск в интернете так и не дал мне хороших результатов.

Comment: https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/58e5ebeceea27017bc851d67 ?

Comment: @Violet, забыл оставить свой ответ, что уже решил проблему. Но все равно спасибо:)